# old files slowing down heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, heroku, load

I did a complete site revamp of my rails site, and pushed the new files to my heroku app.

I noticed that the server response time went from 0.5 seconds to nearly 2.5 seconds to initialize, even though the site itself is leaner.

Is it possible that heroku is using old files?  Is there a good way to clean out the server (I want to keep the database obviously) of anything that might be stored?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

> Is it possible that heroku is using old files?

Only if you're application is still using them. Each time you push code to Heroku, a new dyno is generated, and the previous one recycled.

You likely haven't optimized your site since your revamp; caching, query optimizations, etc.